# Inversion vs "of"

Tags: word-order

I'm sometimes confused about which version to use.

Examples :

- "The parts of the body" *or* "The body parts"
- "The logs of the server" *or* "The server logs"

Are there any rules to choose between "of the" or an inversion?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are actually grammatically correct and convey the same meaning; it's just that most times an inversion is simply more concise than if you'd used "of the" (case in point: "the parts of the body" is five words long, "the body parts" is three words long).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to realize that there does  not exist a systematic correspondence.

- the countries of 0Europe → <s>The Europe countries</s> (instead, but comparatiely rare: "Europe's countries")
- the colours of the sky →  <s>The sky colours</s> (instead, but comparatiely rare: "The sky's  colours")

Second, the form with "of" is very often more common and feels more natural.

Nevertheless, the books in which can be found the following combinations are many; sometimes it is hardly acceptable.

- forest parts,  house parts, bed parts, book parts…

For instace, if you research "the hand parts"  you find a  page where the term  "the parts of the hand" is used almost exclusiely. ([the hand parts](https://www.google.com/search?q=+the+hand+parts+&client=firefox-b-d&ei=Tm4HY6O9FY6-acraEw&ved=0ahUKEwijnIyXguL5AhUOXxoKHUrtBAAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=+the+hand+parts+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEBMyCAgAEB4QFhATMggIABAeEBYQEzIICAAQHhAWEBMyCAgAEB4QFhATMggIABAeEBYQEzIICAAQHhAWEBM6BwgAEEcQsAM6CggAEB4QCBANEBM6CAgAEB4QBxATOgoIABAeEAcQBRATOgoIABAeEAgQBxATOggIABAeEAUQEzoICAAQHhAIEBM6CggAEB4QDxAWEBM6BAgAEEM6DgguEIAEELEDEIMBENQCOgcILhDUAhBDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToFCAAQgAQ6CgguELEDEIMBEEM6BQguEIAEOgcIIRCgARAKOgoIIRAeEA8QFhAdOggIIRAeEBYQHToICAAQHhAIEAc6BQghEKABSgQIQRgASgUIQBIBMUoECEYYAFDsJ1iqyQVgmOcFaAJwAXgAgAGZAYgB8g-SAQQzLjE1mAEAoAECoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz))

"Body parts" is about to attain to the status of a full-fledged noun.

[image]

It can be seen from the ngram that the "*of*" structure was preferred but  that has been changing over the years.

In   constructing the form without "of"  the base that subcategorizes   the  second is placed in  front. (**CoGEL**)

Since in "the parts of the body"  the word "part" represents the category that the speaker is interested in, the word "body" is first.